# Why is my javascript .push method adding too many objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I am learning Javascript and have run into an issue with the push method. When I use it within a loop it is making my array 33 items instead of just adding 3 to the list. Initial list is 1-10 items long, user defined. I initiated all the variables in the beginning of the script, and the variable items is only manipulated when the user initially tells me how long the array will be. From there it is basic exercises in array methods, and this is the one that is giving me problems. Following is the push part of the code. I appreciate any feedback and will put more code up if anyone feels it is necessary.

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
        newfood = prompt("Please enter food " + (i + 1) + ".");
    foods.push(newfood);
}

document.write("<ol>");
i = 0; //resetting variable i to 0
for (i = 0 ; i < items + 3 ; i++){
    document.write("<li>" + foods[i] + "</li><br>");
}
document.write("</ol>");
```

Comment: What is your `items` variable? Your 2nd loop ought to read `for(i = 0; i < foods.length; i++)` methinks.

Comment: the foods.length would fix it though I was trying to avoid that property for some reason. Thank you for the fix, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're running into string concatenation that's then treating the string as a numeric type. Convert what I assume is a string to an int:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < parseInt(items) + 3 ; i++) {
    document.write("<li>" + foods[i] + "</li><br>");
}
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't get the email that an answer had been made. You hit it on the nose though, it was being treated as a string instead of a number and parseInt was my first thought, once I understood the problem, to fix it. Thank you very much for your time and input.